# Is there any way to configure Oracle without Java support?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, memory, oracle, oracle10g

I've got an Oracle installation that I'm using on my Windows XP workstation to run tests against.  I'm not using Oracle's Java support; is there any way to disable it?  Or is that a good idea?

My main reason is that Oracle's Java process eats up a lot of memory, so if there are good reasons not to do this, I can live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can uninstall the JVM if you don't need it. You can also set the java pool size to zero which should also accomplish what you want.